# Microsoft 365 E5 instant sandbox login issue

Tags: office365, sandbox

I have successfully created a Microsoft 365 E5 instant sandbox. When I go to the dashboard from the email, it prompts me to sign in with the account I created during setup

Then it says
"You don't have access to this
Your sign-in was successful, but you don't have permission to access this resource."

I have a 90 day trial yet I cant sign in to access anything. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

See whether you have any cached login to any other tenant.
Better to try logging in from an incognito window with the admin account you created as part of the Dev Tenant setup.

Comment: I had same error, but the fault was that user's password had expired. But even after reseting the password, I needed to clear cache (used private/incognito window in browser).